# Pressing "Enter" on keyboard causes imeAction button to change to a return button in emulator

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` which looks a bit like the following:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
       />
```

Additionally, I have both an `OnKeyListener` and an `OnEditorActionListener` set on this `EditText`. The application is being run in an emulator.

Below this input is a button that navigates the user to another screen.

Upon entering a value into this input and pressing "Enter" on my machine's keyboard, the input is submitted (as expected), however what was the "done" key on the on screen keyboard switches to a "return" key. Upon clicking this on screen "return" key, it appears that the button below the input somehow receives a "click" event, navigating the user to another screen. Additionally, clicking this "return" key does not activate either the `OnKeyListener` or `OnEditorActionListener`.

Questions:

1. Why does the action button suddenly change to a return button after pressing enter?
2. Why does clicking the return button not activate any listeners?
3. Why does clicking the return button cause an unrelated button to receive a click event?

Comment: The focus changed from the text field to the next focusable field.  Which not having an imeOptions used the default for that keyboard.  Easiest way to avoid this-  call hideKeyboard in your done button handler.

Comment: @GabeSechan Does a button count as a "focusable" field? I understand the button can gain focus, but it isn't a field, and I would not expect the keyboard to be used to interact with a button.

Comment: yes. Focusable element may be a better term

Comment: Is there a way to simply prevent "enter" from focusing another element?